# Hibernate batch insert and update from excel

Tags: java, hibernate, session, batch-processing

I need to read excel and

1. inserting row if data does not exist
2. update row if data exists

What I am doing in the loop is

```
//Begin transaction
//for(each row in excel){
//  MyObject obj = readObject(row);
//  session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
/}
//Close transaction
```

I am assigning the ID property to POJO using one excel column. 
The issue is that there can be multiple rows in excel with same ID. So I end up having multiple objects created with same ID. And then, on invocation of **saveOrUpdate** I get 
**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException**

I've read many articles on StackOverflow, but didnt find a way it works.
I've even tried doing this, but it didn't work

```
//Begin transaction
//for(row in excel){
//  MyObject obj = readObject(row);
//  session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
//  session.flush();
//  session.clear();
/}
//Close transaction
```

Also tried the following, but got **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**

```
//Begin transaction
//for(row in excel){
//  MyObject obj = readObject(row);
//  session.merge(obj);
//  session.flush();
//  session.clear();
/}
//Close transaction

//Begin transaction
//for(row in excel){
//  MyObject obj = readObject(row);
//  session.merge(obj);
/}
//Close transaction
```

Please help.

Here is one of the stackTraces:

*org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2886)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3386)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at com.nextscm.rms.db.dao.AbstractDao.flush(AbstractDao.java:51)
used by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'owner1:warehouseid1:skuid98238:08-11-2016' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 55 more*

Comment: please share detailed exception stack trace

Comment: Provided the stack trace

Comment: Below excerpt from stacktrace clearly tells what is the issue    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'owner1:warehouseid1:skuid98238:08-11-2016' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I understand the issue. Which is why I am trying to use saveOrUpdate. But it isn't working

Comment: make sure that you have valid implementation of equals and hashcode in MyObject.java

Comment: Tried with equals and hashcode also. Sill same kind of issues